# One Hibernate FullTextEntityManager across multiple web-apps

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

How to share one jar with model (JPA entities and DAOs, Hibernate as provider with Hibernate Search extension) among multiple Web-apps deployed on same server (Tomcat)? Put model jar to lib folder?

Updated:

Let me be more precise - as I'm using hibernate, I do care about transactions conflicts but this, as I see, can be fixed with @Version annotation, but what about Hibernate Search that builds it's index separately in one place, will it be corrupted if more than one hibernate FulltextEntitymanager try to access it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding this JAR as a maven dependency in said web apps doesn't do the trick ?

[Reference to publish your jar to local repo](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Then you can add your locale repo to your maven settings file and add the dependency in your pom.xml file of tha various web apps.

The downside to that is that if you work in a team, everyone will have to follow the same steps, at least the part where you install your jar with model to your local repo and probably also the maven settings file modification to add the local repo.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I not sure about Hibernate Search here. Please see my updated question